# How to test .NET builds with gitlab-runner locally?

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to test my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for a .NET project locally, but am having trouble doing so. To be able to ask a useful question here I've tried to create instructions for a minimal repro, assuming a fully up to date Windows 10 Pro machine with Visual Studio 2017 installed.

1. Create a new .NET 4.6.2 Console Application "GlabTest" in Visual Studio in the following location: `c:\experiments\GlabTest`
2. Package Manager Console: `Install-Package NewtonSoft.Json`
3. `Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(1));` as the only line of code in the Main function
4. `.gitlab-ci.yml` file next to the `sln` file with this content:

   ```
   variables:
     RELEASE_FOLDER: 'GlabTest/bin/Release'
     MSBUILD: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'

   stages:
     - build

   build_job:
     stage: build
     script:
       - 'nuget restore'
       - '& "$env:MSBUILD" GlabTest.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild'
     artifacts:
       paths:
         - '$env:RELEASE_FOLDER\'
   ```
5. `.gitignore` with this:

   ```
   .vs/
   **/[Pp]ackages/*
   [Bb]in/
   [Oo]bj/
   ```
6. `git init` and `git add .` and `git commit -m "Weeee"`
7. Follow [these instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html) and download to `c:\gl\gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe`
8. Open PowerShell, go to the `sln` folder
9. `& 'C:\gl\gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe' exec shell build_job`

This will spit out all sorts of errors:

- "`Since gitLab Runner 10.0 this command is marked as DEPRECATED`" without any hints on how to migrate away from `exec`
- Cloning the repo into a subfolder of itself (`.../GlabTest/builds/0/project-0`)
- "`& was unexpected at this time.`" near the end
- all sorts of output issues, e.g. the last line is:

  ```
  [31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit status 255
  ```

Before I dive deeper into a "DEPRECATED" command I should probably step back and ask: what is the recommended way to iterate locally a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with Powershell build on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Why does it say DEPRECATED, what should we use instead?]

Well, there *is not new way to do this*, [it seems `exec` is being deprecated without a current replacement](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2710).

> Cloning the repo into a subfolder of itself ...

No clue yet how to fix this.

> & was unexpected at this time

That's because `cmd` is the default shell on windows, so you should instead do:

```
& 'C:\gl\gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe' exec shell build_job --shell powershell
```

(Note the `--shell powershell` at the end.)

> all sorts of output issues

No clue what's going on there. Possibly your terminal isn't compatible with the way gitlab-runner.exe is trying to colorize output?